# Using Subreport in Crystal Report and ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, subreport

My main Report and SubReport is very similar to each other, using same parameters and formula the only difference is their order in the derails section. Now When I load the subreport in the report and run it, ASP.NET keeps on asking to enter values for the parameters used.

[image]

I think I need to have a code that loads the subreport.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        

       report.Load(Server.MapPath("MonthlySalesReportP.rpt"));


        report.SetDatabaseLogon
          ("sa", "pw", @"databasename, "servername");  

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
        CrystalReportViewer1.SeparatePages = false;



        report.SetParameterValue(0, MonthLastYear);
        report.SetParameterValue(1, MonthCurrent);
        report.SetParameterValue(2, MonthPrevious);
        report.SetParameterValue(3, RP);
        report.SetParameterValue(4, Loc);
        report.SetParameterValue(5, cms);
        report.SetParameterValue(6, YearCurrent);
        report.SetParameterValue(7, YearPrevious);
        report.SetParameterValue(8, YearLastYear);
        report.SetParameterValue(9, FullName);


}
```

**Should I include a code that is needed to read the subreport?**

I see this suggestion

```
report.SetDataSource(dtproductview);
report.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(dsHeader.Tables[0]);
report.Subreports[1].SetDataSource(dsFooter.Tables[0]);
```

But i do not have a datatable or dataset, it is directly from a stored procedure

Comment: Have you already tried moving the part where you set the parameters before the part where you set CrystalReportViewer1 properties?

Comment: move to? where should I move that part?

Comment: Something like this http://pastebin.com/derbNDJg

Comment: I see. Tried it just now still the same. not working

Comment: Are your subreport's parameters linked to the parameters given to the main report? http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/774764/how-to-pass-a-parameter-from-main-report-to-subrep (see solution 1)

Comment: Is there a fast way to automatically link the parameter in the sub report to the parameter in main report? where I do not have to change the formula for the new link paramter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Have you tried Linking the parameters of the subreport to the main report?

   (`Change subreport links` in Subreport context menu)
2. You can try, also:

   `report.Subreports[0].SetParameterValue(0, MonthLastYear);`

Comment: Hi trying number 2 suggestion now

Comment: With regards to number 1 suggestion, currently the sub report has its own paramaters with it identical to the main report. Will it be okay to change its link?